# Расстановка зaпятых

Tags: запятая

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как верно расставить запятые в предложении? Или они здесь не нужны? "Фестиваль начнется в июне в большом тенистом парке".

Answer (score 1):

"Фестиваль начнется в июне в большом тенистом парке".

Как верно указано, в данном варианте предложение неосложненное, обстоятельства времени и места не являются однородными.

Обстоятельство места "в большом тенистом парке" можно представить в качестве уточняющего, но тогда предложение должно быть распространенным, например:"Фестиваль начнется в самом начале июня, в большом тенистом парке".

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! А если будет просто "в начале июня"? То есть: "Фестиваль начнется в начале июня, в большом тенистом парке", то запятая нужна будет или нет?

Comment: Да, в этом примере обстоятельство также можно обособить, то есть структура предложения позволяет это сделать. Таким образом, мы увеличиваем объем предложения, и тогда две части предложения читаются как самостоятельные сообщения. Кстати, общая семантика предложения при обособлении выражена лучше.

Comment: Спасибо, что разъяснили. Кстати, вопрос немного из другой оперы, но если "большой тенистый парк" заменить на "широко раскинутый тенистый парк", то запятая все равно не понадобится между "широко раскинутый" и "тенистый"?

Comment: Получится: "Фестиваль начнется в самом начале июня, в широко раскинутом тенистом парке". Здесь нам удобно считать эти определения неоднородными (обозначают разные признаки), но в других случаях можно придать им сближенное значение (раскрывают тему подходящего для отдыха места)и считать однородными, например: В широко раскинутом, тенистом парке можно приятно провести время.

Answer (score 1):

Никак не могу согласиться с предложенным 2-м вариантом. Обычно в таком случае говорят: "Нет причин для постановки знаков препинания". Все словв этом предложении являются разными членами предложения, между ними нет ничего общего, особенно между обстоятельствами времени и места, поэтому запятая здесь абсолютно не нужна. А теперь о  моем мнимом покушении на свободу творческого отношения к фразе: "Свобода никогда не означала произвольное обращение с общепринятыми правилами и элементарной логикой. Что касается приводимого Софией примера, то я бы написал так: "Встретимся завтра, в 15 часов, (уточняющее обстоятельство времени)около главного фонтана". Второе предложение, написанное Софией, можно трактовать как сложное, вторая часть которого - неполное предложение: "Встречаемся где, (встречаемся)когда?"

Comment: У Вас все как-то абсолютно, никакой свободы для художника слова. А если так: "Встретимся завтра в 15 00, около главного фонтана". Это на ВВЦ. Придете? Или вот ещё: «Встречаемся где, когда?»  Ваш комментарий?

Comment: Виктор, тогда вот еще задачка: "Когда и где встречаемся?" Какие члены предложения соединяет союз И? А свободу всё-таки ущемляете. Мне не хотелось бы время встречи считать уточняющим и относить его на второй план. Допустим, что "завтра" - это уже известный нам факт, а главное - договориться о времени. Мне хотелось бы так: координата места, координата времени.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще не нужны, простое не осложненное предложение)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!